# How to replace a snippet in a video without reencoding the whole video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to edit and replace a section of a video without reencoding the whole video.
Here are the steps I think I need to take:

### 1. Find keyframes

#### input:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv=p=0 'example.mkv'
```

#### output:

```
0.000000
1.001000
11.011000
13.430000
20.812000
30.822000
40.832000
50.842000
⋮
```

### 2. Export relevant section

For example, export the snippet `40.832000 → 50.842000`.

### 3. Edit and reencode

After editing that section, I need to reencode it to the original codecs for compatibility with the surrounding video. For example, this is the original codecs:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x1600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

### 4. Inject edit back into the video stream

Finally, I need to use FFmpeg somehow to retain everything from the original file (audio, subtitles, chapters, etc.) and to construct a new video stream (for example, `Stream #0:0`) that is exactly `0 → 40.832000` of the original, the whole edited section, and `50.842000 → end` of the original section.

## My main questions are:

- **A.** How do I trim the video stream in 2. without reencoding?
- **B.** Assuming that the edited video's resolution will remain the same, what is the command for  FFmpeg to encode my edit to the codecs in 3. (and would the video be concatenable with the original video)?
- **C.** How should I go about glueing the sections together? Should I simply trim `Stream #0:0` into sections `v1 = 0 → 40.832` and `v2 = 50.842 → end` and then concatenate a new stream as `new = v1 + edited + v2`?
- **D.** How do I replace `Stream #0:0` with `new`?

And probably the most important question: are my assumptions correct and can this be achieved?

Comment: Regarding... **(a)** Use `-c:v copy` to avoid a re-encode, **(b)** Yes it can concat with the original if encoded as same video settings. **(c)** Yes, go with your suggestion.. **(d)** You can use multiple inputs and `map` the streams into different tracks/streams of the output video.... Yes your assumptions are correct and can be achieved. All commands can be found via Google search...